# Why does the mongodb aggregate $avg code return all of the documents ungrouped?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, average

The same mongodb aggregate `$avg` code that returns only 1 row (expected) directly in mongodb, returns all of the documents (completely ungrouped) and without the `$avg` value also when run inside node.js.  It is basically as I simply did a find on the entire collection and returned all of the documents with all of the columns.  Why is the grouping ignored?

I ran the code directly inside mongodb and there there is only one element returned inside the array.  This is what is expected as I wish to get the average price for all the documents inside the collection, hence the `'null'` _id value.

I tried this with `$sum` too, but no difference.  It is as if the code simply does not see the group section at all, but why does the exact same code work inside mongodb and not inside Node.js?

```
async function findHistoricalStakingAverage(days) {

  let allAverage = await dailyDB.collection('price').aggregate(
      {
        $match: {
          date: {
            $lt: new Date(),
            $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - days))
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          avg: { $avg: "$staking_rate" }
        }
      }
    ).toArray();

 return allAverage;
}
```

Below is the same command run directly in mongo with the expected output of only one item, the average value for all the documents:

```
> db.price.aggregate(
...       {
...         $match: {
...           date: {
...             $lt: new Date(),
...             $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30))
...           }
...         }
...       },
...       {
...         $group: {
...           _id: null,
...           avg: { $avg: "$staking_rate" }
...         }
...       }
...     ).toArray()
[ { "_id" : null, "avg" : 13.848065601345667 } ]
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, You need to wrap aggregation pipeline stages inside `[]`, otherwise it seems to not consider all stages of it :

```
async function findHistoricalStakingAverage(days) {

  let allAverage = await dailyDB.collection('price').aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          date: {
            $lt: new Date(),
            $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - days))
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          avg: { $avg: "$staking_rate" }
        }
      }
    ]).toArray();

 return allAverage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I needed.  Tell me please, when are those brackets needed?  So far, I have neither used them at all in my Node.js mongodb ```find``` nor in the ```aggregate``` commands.  I have used other ```$group``` sections in other queries too, but for the ```$sum``` command and those work.  Perhaps it has something to do with ```$avg``` or with the ```null``` id, or?  What do you think?

Comment: not exactly sure why it's an issue for certain aggregation stages(why it does break after couple stages and doesn't in other cases, haven't found an answer yet - would post it here for sure if I find any) !! But in general it would ideal to wrap all stages in [] as to say it's a pipeline..

Comment: @user3306922 : hey if it does work, can you please mark it accepted that way we can mark this question is solved..

Comment: sure, but how do I do that?  I don't see any button or text resembling that.  Perhaps my reputation is too low for that.  I can also not upvote your answer.  Can you please be so kind and let me know how I can do it?  I only see 'share' and 'edit' for your answer.  Thank you

Comment: Found it; it was the check-mark that I had to toggle to green.  I trust all is good now.  I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @user3306922 : all the best, happy coding :-)